# vue 3 pass strongly typed complex object to component inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass a strongly typed complex object to component inside v-for loop.  I'm getting the following error: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "Data". Expected StoreListItem, got Object

StoreListItem.ts

```
export class StoreListItem {
    description: String | undefined;
    price: Number | undefined;
}
```

StoreListItem.vue

```
<template>
  <p>
    {{Data.description}}
  </p>
  <p>
    {{Data.price}}
  </p>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { reactive, defineComponent} from "vue";
import { StoreListItem } from "@/models/StoreListItem";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "StoreListItem",
  props: {
    Data: StoreListItem,
  },
});
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
      <div v-for="item in featuredItems">
        <store-list-item :Data="item"></store-list-item>
      </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import compStoreListItem from "@/components/StoreListItem.vue";
import { StoreListItem } from "@/models/StoreListItem";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: { "store-list-item": compStoreListItem },
  setup() {
    let featuredItems = ref<StoreListItem[]>([]);

    function loadData(): void {
      var items: StoreListItem[] = [
        { description: "test", price: 10 },
        { description: "test2", price: 20 },
      ];

      featuredItems.value = items;

    }

    onMounted(() => {
      loadData();
    });

    return { featuredItems };
  },
});
</script>
```

The item for the v-for doesn't seem to maintain it's type.  It is just an object.  I want to do something like this: (doesn't work)

```
<div v-for="(item as StoreListItem) in featuredItems">
     <store-list-item :Data="item"></store-list-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if Vue-3 does that but with Vue-2, I don't think you can pass a special type like you did in your prop declaration in the component. You can only specify if the prop is an object and a default value, that's it. Please refer to the validation section for props here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: It works just fine but I get the Vue Warn message.